# Storable empty data declaration

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

I'm attempting to create a Haskell wrapper for a C library. The underlying structs are too complicated to express as explicit types, and I don't actually use them other than for passing between C functions, so I'm using `EmptyDataDecls` to let GHC work it out for me.

What I need is a pointer to one of these data types, but when I attempt to create one with `alloca` it complains that the data is not of the type `Storable`. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface, EmptyDataDecls #-}

module Main where

import Foreign.Marshal.Alloc
import Foreign.Ptr

data Struct

foreign import ccall "header.h get_struct"
    get_struct :: Ptr Struct -> IO ()

main = alloca $ \ptr -> get_struct ptr
```

GHC won't compile this, saying there's no instance for `Storable Struct`. I could implement it myself:

```
instance Storable Struct where
    sizeOf _    = ...
    alignment _ = ...
```

But that comes close to defeating the purpose - I don't want to have to define such things if I don't care what's in the struct.

I've noticed that a pointer to a pointer works fine, because the `Ptr` class is `Storable`. So I can accomplish what I'm aiming for by using `peek` on `ptr` before calling `get_struct`:

```
main = alloca $ \ptr -> do
  ptr <- peek ptr
  get_struct ptr
```

This feels like a hack, though.

Is there a way to get empty data declarations to be considered `Storable` without defining an instance?

Comment: This is a hack.  You never allocate space for the inner pointer; you're just pointing at random memory.  This way lies segfaults.

Comment: So if I legitimately want a pointer to a pointer, I should use two `alloca` calls and then `poke` one pointer into the other, right?

Comment: yes (or use some other form of allocation).  The most common uses for a pointer to a pointer are pointer out values, in which case the bound function makes the allocation, and arrays of strings (think `argv`).  Th

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't allocate something if you don't know how big it is. Is the function just going to ignore its argument? Then pass in a null pointer. Otherwise, you need to actually allocate enough space for the struct - don't cut corners by allocating a zero-byte or pointer-sized buffer, as then the called function will write past the end of your buffer, corrupting memory.

Either finish the data declaration, or write a Storable instance with proper size and alignment values; there's no way around providing size/alignment data in some form.

Comment: You can use a convinient tool like chs for this purpose - it helps you figuring out these values.

Comment: Note that you don't have to define every method of an instance.  If you don't want to marshal the structs to Haskell, only define `sizeOf` and `alignment` but leave `peek` and `poke` undefined (or call error).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that might work for you. I assume that you have access to all of the C header files that define the objects you need to allocate. If that's true, you could write a thin layer of C code for allocating and freeing the C objects. Your Haskell code can then call these C functions without the Haskell code ever needing to know what's behind the pointers.  Haskell can also automatically call the free code when Haskell's garbage collector knows that the objects are no longer needed.